# Deserializing a json to an abstract class in spring cloud functions

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-data-jpa, abstract-class, json-deserialization, spring-cloud-function

I have a java project written using spring cloud functions and deployed in aws lambda. I have a scenario wherein I have an abstract class extended by 3 other classes.

The function catering to the requests receives a request in a json format. The request has data which is appropriate for one of the implementations of the abstract class(might be appropriate for a different implemetation at different times). If the deserialization is successful, the data needs to be persisted in db using spring-jpa.

As the deserialization proceeds automatically, it fails since abstract classes can't be instantiated and deserialization itself will not be able to identify the correct implementation.

Here are my class details:

```
Class A{

    String x;
    String y;
    .
    .
    .
    B b
    .
    .
    
    //gettters and setters



}


public class B {

    String type;
    private C c

}

public abstract class C{

}

public class D extends C{

    string var1;
    string var2;
    
    //setters and getters
}

public class E extends C{

    String var3;
    String var4;
    String var5;
    
    //setters and getters
}
```

and the request json that the function gets

```
{
    "x": "some x value",
    "y": "some y value",
    "b": {
        "type" : "some type",
        "c": {
            "var1": "some var1 value", //these would be three in case of  E
            "var2": "some var2 value"
        }
    }

}
```

The function that receives the request

```
public Function<A, A> getResponse(){
//some code
}
```

Since class C is abstract, deserialization fails as it's not able to decide which of the subclasses should be instantiated. Can someone suggest how to deal with this?

Comment: To benefit from the transparent type conversion feature of spring-cloud-function (which is what you're referring to) the function must define e concrete types. Without fully understanding your design I would say you can change to a `Function<byte[]..>`, receive the raw (unconverted data) and do what you wish with it, but i have to say that it feels wrong. Perhaps you can post a sample code somewhere in github so we can tale a look and suggest something better.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky question edited with some sample code

Comment: If you declare `Function<A, A>`, you effectively not telling us what type are you interested in. You need to communicate it somehow either through function signature or via `contentType` encoded arguments (e.g., `application/foo;type=com.Foo`), and in that case you would need custom MessageConverter - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.2.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#user-defined-message-converters

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky the conversion happens automatically. In my case as well, there are no issues in conversion. Deserialization is successful for all the other fields except 'b' of type B. If I remove B, it deserializes sucessfully. The issue is with B

Comment: I do not see any relation between A and B from your code above, so I am not following. Can you please provide a small reproducible sample and push it to github so we can take a look?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky the json that I shared in the sample code above is A's json i.e. the variables x, y and b(reference variable of B) are part of the A's json structure

Comment: I am not sure i follow as this `public Function<A, A> getResponse(){` will not and should not work unless A is a concrete class. That is an expected behavior. The sample I expect is a full running project that we can import and analize, so please let me know when you have one